# unique_ptr deleter pointer to pointer

Tags: c++, std

I am trying to map a third-party API using a unique_ptr custom deleter. The problem is that the API is as such:

```
x *x_alloc_x(void);

void x_free_x(x **p);
```

The API wants me to provide a pointer to a pointer for it to set to NULL. I have been writing my deleter functor as taking a reference-to-pointer, which I convert to pointer-to-pointer with the "&" operator.

```
struct XDeleter {
    void operator(x *&p) { x_free_x(&p); }
};
```

This has worked with GCC 4.6, but is this actually permitted by the standard? If not, is there a standard-compliant way to map this API to a deleter?

Comment: There's always the trick of making `pointer` a type alias for `x **` and then taking an `x **` in the function call operator (I presume that's what operator you meant).

Comment: I recommend having an overload that takes a `x*&const` in addition, so you don't _have_ to use an lvalue.

Comment: @MooingDuck Did you mean `const` *pointer*? What you have there is a `const` reference (which is illegal).

Comment: Why should a const reference to a pointer be illegal?

Comment: @leemes I think he meant to say that there is no such thing as a const reference, because references are inherently constant in the sense that you can't change the object they reference.

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves Well yes you can **modify** (even reassign) the object via the reference (that's exactly the difference `const` makes), but you can't change **which** object the reference references (in the sense of reseating the reference). Two different things.

Comment: @0x499602D2 Yeah, `void operator(x*const& p) {x*t=p; x_free_x(&t);}`.  My bad.

Comment: Yes, that code is standard-conformant. Just because `p` is a reference doesn't mean that it will conflict with the type of `x**`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is not well-formed. n3797 [unique.ptr.single.dtor]/1 requires in the destructor of `unique_ptr`:

> *Requires:* The expression `get_deleter()(get())` shall be well formed [...]

Where [unique.ptr.single] specifies:

> ```
> pointer get() const noexcept;
> ```

That is, `get()` is a prvalue.

Additionally, [unique.ptr.single]/1

> A client-supplied template argument `D` [the deleter type]
>   shall be a function object type, lvalue-reference to function, or lvalue-reference to function object type
>   for which, given a value `d` of type `D` and a value `ptr` of type `unique_ptr<T, D>::pointer`, the expression
>   `d(ptr)` is valid and has the effect of disposing of the pointer as appropriate for that deleter.

A *value* is a prvalue.

---

The solution has been given in the comments by [Mooing Duck](https://stackoverflow.com/users/845092/mooing-duck):

```
struct XDeleter {
    void operator(x *p)
    { x_free_x(&p); }
};
```

The destructor of `unique_ptr` however is not required to assign `nullptr` to the stored pointer.

Comment: I was afraid of this. I don't actually care that the contained pointer is set to NULL as this only happens in the destructor anyway. I'll eat the extra line and make a copy of the pointer.

Comment: @user2363399 Oops, actually that line isn't necessary. See my edit.